# How to access data from a file upto delimiter in ansible and assign data to a variable and loop playbook according to the variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I have a file data like below:

```
[prod]
product=Admin;Financial;Hrm
```

When I try to access file data I am getting complete line, like `Admin;Financial;Hrm` but for the first loop I have to take only `Admin`, and for the second loop I should get `Financial` and for the third loop I should get the `hrm`.

And I am accessing the file data and assigning it to a variable like:

```
- set_fact: product={{ lookup('ini', 'product type=prod file=vars.properties') }}"
```

And my below playbooks should loop accroding to the product

The playbooks are like below

```
- name: This task is to loop ansible playbook according to inputs with delimiters
  debug: msg="{{product}}"

- include: sudo ansible-playbook create_new_env_adm.yml --extra-vars "Release=3.11.1"
  when: 
    - '"appfolder" == "ADM"'
    - '"product"=="Admin"'`

- include: sudo ansible-playbook create_new_env_fin.yml --extra-vars "Release=3.11.2"
  when:
    - '"appfolder" == "fin"'
    - '"product"=="Financial"'`

- include: sudo ansible-playbook create_new_env_hrm.yml --extra-vars "Release=3.11.3"
  when: 
    - '"appfolder" == "hrm"'
    - '"product"=="Hrm"'
```

Comment: It's not directly related to the question, but I don't think the lookup plugin-call with `type=prod` works with the example file you posted. Does it?　・　Also not related, but the whole idea seems a somewhat strange implementation.　・　Finally you mention some loops in the title and the body, but no loop is in the code, not even a requirement for a loop.

Answer (score 1):

Example syntax (using the [`split` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) to convert the string to a list and a [containment test](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.contains) to check if an element is on the list):

```
when: 
  - "'Admin' in product.split(';')"
```

<sup>You might want to move `.split` to the variable definition for better code readability.</sup>

Comment: Thanks@techraf, `when: "'Admin' in product.split(';')"`  worked for me.

Comment: Please have a look at the Help Center: [do not add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)